# В шезлонге / На шезлонге

Tags: предлоги

Подскажите, будьте добры: *в шезлонге* или *на шезлонге*? Что правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы говорим: *сидеть **в** кресле*, но ***на*** стуле. С когнитивной точки зрения это объясняется так, что стул воспринимается как *поверхность*, а кресло как некое *ограниченное пространство*.

Так, например, одним из частотных прилагательных, сочетающихся с существительным **кресло**, будет **глубокое**:

> **В глубоких креслах** сидели трое довольно пожилых мужчин, видимо, тех самых старейшин.

С шезлонгом дело обстоит сложнее, т.к. этот предмет мебели представляет собой пограничный случай между поверхностью и ограниченным пространством. (Что обусловлено в том числе наличием в его конструкции подвижных частей и возможностью менять форму.)

Соответственно  с ним употребляются оба предлога:

- в шезлонге — 93 вхождения по НКРЯ
- на шезлонге — 9 вхождений по НКРЯ

В вашем конкретном случае выбор предлога будет зависеть от контекста: захотите вы подчеркнуть наличие поверхности (*растянуться на шезлонге*) или внутреннего пространства (*плюхнуться в шезлонг*).